# How to customize Windows Media Player UI programmatically?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-media-player, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have this Skin Programming Reference for Windows Media Player: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/skin-programming-reference

According to that reference `BUTTON.image` is the image attribute that specifies or retrieves the default image of the `BUTTON`, I wanna change the color or skin of a `BUTTONELEMENT` such as play, pause, stop, next, prev, etc., how do I set those properties through an `AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer` object? Is it even possible or does it need something else? I'd appreciate both C# or C++ examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything about skins is explained in the old WMP 9 SDK ([Windows Media Player 9 Series Software Development Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25243)

There is a basic sample, **RemoteSkin**, which implements the **IWMPRemoteMediaServices** as explained at [Using Skins with the Windows Media Player Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/using-skins-with-the-windows-media-player-control)

Skins have the *.wms* or *.wmz* extension and are just zip files with all necessary files inside

You can find many examples of more advanced skins on the Web, like [World Of Warcraft Skin for Windows Media Player](https://www.davidtan.org/world-of-warcraft-skin-for-windows-media-player/) (you can extract the files from *WoW.wmz*)